# Undefined Slot variable in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am getting an error which is "Undefined variable: nav"

In my home.blade.php,I have this code

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    {!! $nav !!}
@endsection
```

And in my header component(header.blade.php)

```
@component('component.header')
    @slot('nav')
       new html
    @endslot
@endcomponent
```

Can you help?
FYI my component is in a component directory in views and home is in views directory

Comment: `$nav` will not be available as a variable. I am not sure what you are doing now, but doing `@slot` you are saying that in your `@component header` you have a `slot` that is called `nav` and you want to add `new html` inside it. I am not sure what are you trying to do with `$nav`. More info about slots in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots).

Comment: In laravel doc, see the title slot, the title is available as a variable for any view. The same thing I want to do. Moreover, I can't access the default $slot variable which all components have.

Comment: In which file, and at which line, does the error occur?